# Make a request to a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In RSpec I'm currently testing API requests using a series of methods that compile effectively to something like this:

```
env = Rack::MockRequest.env_for('/api/v1/projects.json')
Rails.application.call(env)
```

I was wondering if there was a shorter way of making a request to the Rails application in RSpec. I know you can create a controller spec and request specific actions, but I'm more after a way to make a request to a URL and check that the output is what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using Rack::Test for this use case. Example:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rack/test'

describe 'API' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end

  before do
    @password = "12345"
    @project  = Factory(:project)
    @user     = Factory(:user,
                        :password              => @password,
                        :password_confirmation => @password,
                        :project               => @project)

    authorize @user.email, @password
  end

  it "gets projects" do
    get "/api/v1/projects.json"

    last_response.should be_ok
    last_response.body.should == [@project].to_json
    last_response.content_type.should == 'application/json'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The "visit" method seems to work too, but i dont know about the mocking.